# TeX Live Manager broken. How can I unbreak it or diagnose the problem?

Tags: texlive, perl

I am running upstream's TeX Live 2015 on GNU/Linux. TeX Live Manager was successfully used to update the installation at, I think, around 17.00 on 26 June.

Perl packages were updated as part of a system update on 26 June at around 14.00. That is, the last successful use of `tlmgr` occurred *after* the last updates to `perl` packages.

Now, however, on 1 July, `tlmgr` appears to be broken due to something related to `perl`:

```
tlmgr --help
perl: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/auto/List/Util/Util.so: undefined symbol: Perl_xs_apiversion_bootcheck
```

I get the same error for `tlmgr update --all`, `tlmgr update --list` etc. I also get the same error when running as both the dedicated `texlive:texlive` user who manages my TeX Live installation on my machine and when running an informational command such as `tlmgr update --list` using my regular user account.

I admit to little more than a passing acquaintance with `perl`. I'm also not sure whether this is on topic or not, since I'm not sure whether it is a TeX Live issue or an issue with my distro's `perl` packages or a problem specific to me.

- How can I resolve the problem?
- If I can't, how can I workaround it?
- If I can't, how can I diagnose it sufficiently well to think about filing a bug report for whatever turns out to be responsible?

Answer (score 8):

I was about to delete this but then thought it might be better to answer it.

If you are experiencing the same problem ***and you use Arch Linux***, read [this thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1541155#p1541155). Read to the bottom: you do ***not*** need to remove every AUR package and its configuration files and rebuild them all in order to resolve the issue.

That is enough to get `tlmgr` to work again on my machine. However, it is not entirely happy about things due to a bug in this version of `perl`. As you can see, this `perl` really, really doesn't like `line 3109` of `tlmgr`:

```
tlmgr: package repository http://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet
tlmgr: saving backups to /usr/local/texlive/2015/tlpkg/backups
Redundant argument in sprintf at /usr/local/texlive/bin/tlmgr line 3109.
[ 1/23, ??:??/??:??] update: babel-french [310k] (37554 -> 37701) ... done
Redundant argument in sprintf at /usr/local/texlive/bin/tlmgr line 3109.
[ 2/23, 00:03/02:43] update: c90 [96k] (15878 -> 37676) ... done
Redundant argument in sprintf at /usr/local/texlive/bin/tlmgr line 3109.
[ 3/23, 00:05/03:28] update: cjkutils [35k] (37078 -> 37693) ... done
Redundant argument in sprintf at /usr/local/texlive/bin/tlmgr line 3109.
[ 4/23, 00:08/05:07] update: curve2e [666k] (37619 -> 37708) ... done
Redundant argument in sprintf at /usr/local/texlive/bin/tlmgr line 3109.
[ 5/23, 00:11/02:48] update: dozenal [416k] (36169 -> 37698) ... done
Redundant argument in sprintf at /usr/local/texlive/bin/tlmgr line 3109.
[ 6/23, 00:16/02:58] update: eledmac [1977k] (37639 -> 37699) ... done
Redundant argument in sprintf at /usr/local/texlive/bin/tlmgr line 3109.
[ 7/23, 00:21/01:41] update: enotez [465k] (32873 -> 37678) ... done
Redundant argument in sprintf at /usr/local/texlive/bin/tlmgr line 3109.
[ 8/23, 00:29/02:03] update: fithesis [2746k] (37661 -> 37712) ... done
Redundant argument in sprintf at /usr/local/texlive/bin/tlmgr line 3109.
[ 9/23, 00:35/01:28] update: garuda-c90 [5k] (30642 -> 37677) ... done
Redundant argument in sprintf at /usr/local/texlive/bin/tlmgr line 3109.
[10/23, 00:37/01:33] update: l3build [567k] (37132 -> 37679) ... done
Redundant argument in sprintf at /usr/local/texlive/bin/tlmgr line 3109.
[11/23, 00:40/01:33] update: norasi-c90 [10k] (30642 -> 37675) ... done
Redundant argument in sprintf at /usr/local/texlive/bin/tlmgr line 3109.
[12/23, 00:48/01:51] update: pstricks [6797k] (35439 -> 37707) ... done
Redundant argument in sprintf at /usr/local/texlive/bin/tlmgr line 3109.
[13/23, 01:00/01:12] update: siunitx [729k] (37589 -> 37680) ... done
Redundant argument in sprintf at /usr/local/texlive/bin/tlmgr line 3109.
[14/23, 01:03/01:11] update: termmenu [472k] (37613 -> 37700) ... done
Redundant argument in sprintf at /usr/local/texlive/bin/tlmgr line 3109.
[15/23, 01:07/01:14] update: texlive-docindex [212k] (37652 -> 37703) ... done
Redundant argument in sprintf at /usr/local/texlive/bin/tlmgr line 3109.
[16/23, 01:09/01:15] update: texlive-scripts [87k] (37633 -> 37696) ... done
Redundant argument in sprintf at /usr/local/texlive/bin/tlmgr line 3109.
[17/23, 01:12/01:18] update: upmethodology [542k] (37038 -> 37694) ... done
Redundant argument in sprintf at /usr/local/texlive/bin/tlmgr line 3109.
[18/23, 01:18/01:21] update: xindy [531k] (37650 -> 37705) ... done
Redundant argument in sprintf at /usr/local/texlive/bin/tlmgr line 3267.
[19/23, 01:21/01:22] auto-install: arabi-add (37709) [168k] ... done
Redundant argument in sprintf at /usr/local/texlive/bin/tlmgr line 3267.
[20/23, 01:22/01:22] auto-install: br-lex (37711) [99k] ... done
Redundant argument in sprintf at /usr/local/texlive/bin/tlmgr line 3109.
[21/23, 01:23/01:23] update: collection-langarabic [1k] (35139 -> 37709) ... done
Redundant argument in sprintf at /usr/local/texlive/bin/tlmgr line 3109.
[22/23, 01:24/01:24] update: collection-latexextra [5k] (37660 -> 37712) ... done
Redundant argument in sprintf at /usr/local/texlive/bin/tlmgr line 3109.
[23/23, 01:25/01:25] update: collection-publishers [1k] (37661 -> 37710) ... done
tlmgr: package log updated: /usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-var/web2c/tlmgr.log
running mktexlsr ...
done running mktexlsr.
running mtxrun --generate ...
done running mtxrun --generate.
running updmap-sys ...
done running updmap-sys.
```

Version information for `perl`:

```
This is perl 5, version 22, subversion 0 (v5.22.0) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi
```

The guru responsible for `tlmgr` has [stated](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/253072/tex-live-manager-broken-how-can-i-unbreak-it-or-diagnose-the-problem/253074?noredirect=1#comment604235_253074) that these warnings are due to a bug in `perl` which has been reported and will get corrected in an update so these warnings will disappear in time. Meanwhile, they are harmless and should be ignored.

If you are experiencing the original issue ***and you do not use Arch***, leave a comment stating your distro and I will try to generalise this answer. Right now, however, I'm assuming this is going to be Arch-specific.

Comment: I think this is just because of the Perl version, and nothing to do with Arch or any other distribution specifically.  It appears to be a result of https://metacpan.org/pod/perldiag#Redundant-argument-in-s , caused by line 3109 using `sprintf ('%*2$s', $currnr, $totalnrdigits)`.  Unfortunately, it's not clear how to fix this, since the current `perldoc` `sprintf` page still lists this as recommended useage:  http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html#(minimum)-width .

Comment: @LSpice Oh, I agree. I think the complaint about the line is just due to the perl version. When I talk about the problem being specific to Arch, I mean the original problem described in the question. That problem is unlikely to affect other distros because they do not work in the same way in terms of packaging. There is no equivalent of AUR in most cases.

Comment: Concerning the warning of "redundant argument", this is a bug in perl 5.22.0 and is already reported and acked by the perl devs. Just ignore, it is nothing serious.

Comment: Thanks @norbert. That was already my plan but it is good to have official sanction! I've edited my answer to add this information.